# CRMException: Expected only one default business unit team

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I've created a plugin to set some custom fields on the **businessunit** entity when it's created.

I registered the plugin and confirmed the context message is *Create*.

Now, when I create a new businessunit, I get the exception message **"Expected only one default business unit team"**.

I'm not setting the default team and even went so far as to remove the attribute before I save the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was running in the context of *Create* and calling *Update* to save but the entity that hadn't been officially created yet.

I removed the Update() function because CRM will save my added attributes when it creates the record.